# delete input based on index of a click event from parent vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I'm working with BootstrapVue.

I want to `splice` my inputs in my  `child.vue` after clicking on a button in my `parent.vue`.

But every time I delete something in my parent.vue - which I can promise that it's working - only the last Input element in my child.vue will be deleted.

If you want to try it do following (you can copy paste the code and run it):

1. Add 3 Inputs
2. Open every Input and write a number into it like `Input 1 -> 1111`, `Input 2 -> 2222` and `Input 3 -> 3333` *(you can also add more Input Informations, but it's not really relevant in here)*
3. Delete for example the second Input, normally it should now be like `Input 1 -> 1111`, `Input 2 -> 3333` but it's always `Input 1 -> 1111` and `Input 2 is still 2222`, because it's always deleting the last input Informations..

How can I solve this problem, that the correct input Informations will be deleted as well?

Thank You very much!

*update*:

**The mistake is that the `index` in my `parent.vue` is changing after deleting something, but in my `child.vue` it did not delete the correct `index` and also did not recreate all other `indexes`**

code in my parent.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="inputArea mt-2" v-for="(id, indexParent) in inputs" :key="indexParent">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <b-button-group>
          <b-button class="col-md-6" v-b-toggle="'newInput' + indexParent" variant="danger">Input</b-button>
          <b-button class="col-md-6" @click="deleteThis(indexParent)" variant="danger">Delete</b-button>
        </b-button-group>
      </div>

      <child :key="indexParent" :indexParent="indexParent" ref="ChildComponent" />
    </div>

    <div class="mt-3 mb-3 ml-3 mr-3">
      <b-button @click="addThis()" variant="success">Add Input</b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

import child from './child.vue'

export default {
  name: "parent",

  components: {
    child,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{}],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    deleteThis(indexParent) {
      this.inputs.splice(indexParent, 1);
      this.$refs.ChildComponent[indexParent].deleteThisFromParent(indexParent);
    },

    addThis() {
      this.inputs.push({});
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

my child.vue:

```
<template>
  <b-collapse visible :id="'newInput' + indexParent" class="mt-2">
    <div v-for="(id, indexChild) in inputs" :key="indexChild">
    <table class="table table-striped mt-2">
      <tbody>
        <h5 class="ml-1">Input Informations</h5>
        <tr>
          <div class="mt-2">Input</div>
          <b-form-input></b-form-input>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

    <b-button @click="addInputInfo()">Add Input Informations</b-button>
  </b-collapse>
</template>



<script>
export default {
  name: "child",

  methods: {
    deleteThisFromParent(indexParent) {
      console.log(this.inputs); //Here I get the correct input which I want to delete
      console.log(indexParent); //correct index of parent.vue
      this.inputs.splice(); //here it deletes the last Input everytime.. 
    },

    addInputInfo() {
      this.inputs.push({});
    },
  },

  props: ["indexParent"],

  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{}],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer.

Setting an unique id in my array was the solution!

*Changings in my template:* Set `:key` to `id.id` (which I will create in my script) and pass after clicking my `deleteButton` my `unique ID` to methods.

```
<div class="inputArea mt-2" v-for="(id, indexParent) in inputs" :key="id.id">
  ....
  <b-button class="col-md-6" @click="deleteThis(id.id)" variant="danger">Delete</b-button>
  ....

</div>
```

*Changings in script:* Set `id: null`, and give the first automatically generated input -> `id = 0`. After that go to methods and reference `splice` to the `index` which I'm getting after search over the complete `array` with `map`. In `addInput` I set the unique Id each time my button will be clicked.

```
data() {
    return {
      id: null, 
      inputs: [{
        id: 0,
      }],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    deleteThis(id) {
      this.inputs.splice(id.id, 1);
    },

    addThis() {
      this.inputs.push({
        id: this.id += 1
      });
    },
  },
```

Last step is to change the passed values to my `child.vue`:

```
<child :key="id.id" :indexParent="id.id"/>
```

After that everything where `indexParent` is still included could be changed to `id.id` -

This is working out for me well!

Answer (score 0):

In your child component change`this.inputs.splice();` in deleteThisFromParent() to `this.inputs.splice(indexParent, 1)`

Comment: this is not working out! - it still have the same Output like I it declared it in my question on number ```3```...